# how to solve problem with modelview controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i am new to iphone. what i did is creating a class with name classA. In viewdidload of classA i declare a modelview controller and display some text and hide the model view controller afetr 4 sec and create another view in the viewdidload.this is fine but while rotating the simulator to landscape mode simulator automatically rotates to portrait and after 4 sec it back to landscape mode. I already write (Bool)shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation function.how can i solve this pls help me.

Comment: please give more details, name your objects in your explanations, provide code samples, etc..  don't be lazy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure you set your view's autoresizingmask correctly.